# Which is the best way to fetch records from table with > 10 million rows of data?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am working with postgres and php.

I have tens of millions of records in my table and want hourly,monthly and yearly data from that table.

If I select hour then it should result hourly records within selected range.

Should I implement Views, temporary tables or something else whatever useful for this for better performance?

Comment: See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization

Comment: The answer is "it depends". If we can see your table schema, some sample queries and some execution times, that will give us something to go on. You could benefit from the techniques you mention, and sharding may also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any indexes on the date columns?

If you are aggregating the data for a report, then you could create a batch job that populates an [Aggregated Fact Table](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/aggregate-fact-table-cube/) each night.